# Android não achando classe dentro de uma Jar. O que fazer?

Tags: android, jar

Este é o erro:`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: br.org.projeto.precos.bean.Lista`

onde o "br.org.projeto.precos.bean.Lista" é o Jar do qual estou tentando usar uma classe. Eu importei tudo certinho, coloquei na pasta libs, no Java Build Paths eu adicionei o Jar em todos os lugares possíveis mas estou com este erro, o que pode ser?

Answer (score 2):

Verifique se, no Java Build Path, você **marcou** "Include" neste jar. Pode ser que ele não esteja sendo incluído ao compilar e gerar o APK do seu aplicativo.

Algo como na imagem abaixo:

[image: Tela Java Build Path - guia Order and Export]

Comment: Eu já marquei todas as opções aí.